# RotateFlipType helper functions?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap, rotation

I've repeatedly found myself wanting to deal with the RotateFlipType in a more modular manner.

For example, at any given time I want to store a single RotateFlipType enum, while giving the user access to buttons to allow flipping and rotating one click at a time.  I need to store this later when I need to apply the RotateFlipType to the data.

So basically I need to store everything seperately across multiple variables.  Or I need to have logic such as:

```
private RotateFlipType ApplyHorizontalFlip(RotateFlipType oldFlip)
{
    switch (oldFlip)
    {
        case RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone:
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;

        case RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX:
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX;

        case RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY:
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY;

        case RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY:
            return RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY;

        case RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone:
            return RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone;

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Are there any helper methods build into the framework, or that anyone knows of?  Basically to take any existing RotateFlipType and modify it by rotating or flipping to give a new value.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicate values, RotateNoneFlipNone is the exact same thing as Rotate180FlipXY for example.  There are only 8 distinct values.  Use a tool like Reflector to see the values.  Which lets you create a small lookup table from an array with 8 elements.

Comment: I can see the 8 different values by clicking Go To Definition in Visual Studio.  I am still finding it painful to work with them.  Even if I store each value seperately (rotation, flipX, and flipY), it's a pain to convert them to an enum.  It's seemingly pages and pages of switch statements.

Comment: Type "lookup table" in a google query and take the first hit.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to store flip and rotation separately until the moment of rendering. I uses RotateFlipType for the flip value, and a number for the degree. I use these methods to combine them into the appropriate RotateFlipType value.

I'd suggest using your own enum instead of RotateFlipType as I've done here, especially if this is exposed as an external API.

```
    private double normalizeTo90Intervals(double d){
        d = d % 360; //Coalesce multiples
        if (d < 0) d += 360; //Force positive
        //Use manual rounding
        if (d >= 315 && d < 360) return 0;
        if (d >= 0 && d < 45) return 0;
        if (d >=45 && d < 135) return 90;
        if (d >= 135 && d < 225) return 180;
        if (d >= 225 && d < 315) return 270;
        return 0; //to make compiler happy
    }

    private RotateFlipType combineFlipAndRotate(RotateFlipType flip, double angle) {
        angle = normalizeTo90Intervals(angle);
        if (flip == 0) return (RotateFlipType)(int)(angle / 90);
        else if (flip == (RotateFlipType)4) return (RotateFlipType)(int)(4 + (angle / 90));
        else if (flip == (RotateFlipType)6) {
            if (angle == 0) return (RotateFlipType)6;
            if (angle == 90) return (RotateFlipType)7;
            if (angle == 180) return (RotateFlipType)4;
            if (angle == 270) return (RotateFlipType)5;
        } else if (flip == (RotateFlipType)2) {
            if (angle == 0) return (RotateFlipType)2;
            if (angle == 90) return (RotateFlipType)3;
            if (angle == 180) return (RotateFlipType)0;
            if (angle == 270) return (RotateFlipType)1;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Valid flip values are RotateNoneFlipNone, RotateNoneFlipX, RotateNoneFlipY, and RotateNoneFlipXY. Rotation must be specified with Rotate or srcRotate instead. Received: " + flip.ToString());
    }
```

FYI, have you heard of http://imageresizing.net/?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
    public static RotateFlipType RotateLeft(RotateFlipType rotateFlip)
    {
        int rotate = (int)rotateFlip % 4;
        int flip = (int)rotateFlip / 4;
        return (RotateFlipType)((rotate + (flip == 0 ? 3 : 1)) % 4 + flip * 4);
    }

    public static RotateFlipType RotateRight(RotateFlipType rotateFlip)
    {
        int rotate = (int)rotateFlip % 4;
        int flip = (int)rotateFlip / 4;
        return (RotateFlipType)((rotate + (flip == 0 ? 1 : 3)) % 4 + flip * 4);
    }

    public static RotateFlipType FlipHorizontal(RotateFlipType rotateFlip)
    {
        int rotate = (int)rotateFlip % 4;
        int flip = (int)rotateFlip / 4;
        return (RotateFlipType)(rotate + (1 - flip) * 4);
    }

    public static RotateFlipType FlipVertical(RotateFlipType rotateFlip)
    {
        int rotate = (int)rotateFlip % 4;
        int flip = (int)rotateFlip / 4;
        return (RotateFlipType)((rotate + 2) % 4 + (1 - flip) * 4);
    }
```